# Выход за кавычки в IDE

Tags: ide, phpstorm, netbeans, sublime-text

При включенной функции автоматической подстановки вторых кавычек происходит следующая ситуация: пишем строку "Moscow|", и курсор находится в кавычках, при отключении данной функции такой проблемы нет. Но в автоподстановке есть свои плюсы, получается палка о двух концах, отсюда и вопрос, есть ли какой-то хоткей для выхода из кавычек, чтобы не клацать стрелку "вправо"?

Comment: По вводу кавычки курсор должен просто пермещаться вправо.

Comment: при кодинге не использую мышку

Comment: у меня прекрасно перемещается. В sublime и в idea (у Вас это phpstorm). Возможно, это в какой то специфичной IDE.

Comment: Все работает нормально, просто я феерически туп и не попробовал нажать на ", думал, что она продублируется...